# Как использовать имя пользователя для входа вместо электронной почты в laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel

Как использовать имя пользователя для входа вместо  электронной почты в laravel 5.3?

Я в документации прочитал но так и не понял 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#included-authenticating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в

> App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php

Этот код:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'name';//строка name в таблице users
}
```